# Not able to create file for writing in "Lenovo IdeaTab"

Tags: android, file, fwrite

The app is to write some data every second on file. This is working in other tabs & phones but in "**Lenovo IdeaTab" (4.1)** is able to create directory but not able to create file to write in it.

Below is the code, I am using to write in file:

```
public void writeDataInFile(String dataString)
{       File logFile = null;
try {

    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/file_name_xyz");
    boolean success = true;
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        success = folder.mkdir();
    }
    if (success) {
        // Do something on success
        String file_path = folder+"/"+currentFileName+".txt";

        logFile = new File(file_path);
        if (!logFile.exists())
        {
            try
            {
                logFile.createNewFile();

                //BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
                BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true)); 
                buf.append("\nxyz: \n");
                buf.newLine();
                buf.close();

            } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Do something else on failure 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to write", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    try
    {
        //BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
        BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true)); 
        buf.append(dataString);
        buf.newLine();
        buf.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//Write internal storage -- data/data/xyzzz
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(currentFileName, Context.MODE_APPEND);
    fos.write(dataString.getBytes());
    fos.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify which version of Android is installed on the Tablet and then lookup file IO API in the Android Docs for that version of Android. I'm pretty sure they changed some things when it comes to accessing files in some of the later versions of the API.